# How to sort in PostgreSQL by uppercase first and after by alphabetically?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I query database with:

```
select *
from users
order by name
```

results are like this:

```
Adam
AVA
adrian
James
JESSICA
John
```

I would like to have rows in order like:

1. rows with all uppercase
2. rows with first letter or more uppercase
3. rows alphabetically

Example:

```
AVA
JESSICA
Adam
James
John
adrian
```

But anyway for me will be enough to:

```
AVA
JESSICA
Adam
adrian
James
John
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `CASE WHEN` and testing uppercase;

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN name = UPPER(name) THEN 1
           WHEN LEFT(name, 1) = UPPER(LEFT(name, 1)) THEN 2
           ELSE 3
       END toOrder
FROM users
ORDER BY toOrder, name ASC
```

[Tested on PostgreSQL 13](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCoNG4EDSp6wKKEQBtGaDY/0)

Comment: You are saving my life ;)
If I could ask I have one more question to you ;)

What If I would like to have order like this:
AVA
Adam
JOHN
JESsica
Jan

So I would like to have sorted alphabetically but in each letter should be uppercase first

Comment: It's not so easy i think. Storing count of uppercase letter of name in a different field can help to do that. How many letter the name field accepts?

Comment: A lot. About 30

Comment: Please explain why `JOHN` < `JESsica`. I still don't understand.

Comment: Because JOHN has 4 uppercase letter, JESsica has 3 :)

Comment: yep, thats ture sddk.